# Missing params when using a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters, partial

let me start that I am new to rails, so far I have been able to solve all the issue I have had until now. I can confirm that my database is set and the relationships are working. Here is my issue, the app is similar to a project management tool. I have users that can create ski swaps and then search for vendors, then I render the results with javascript( ajax) so I dont have to reload the page. I added a badge so that I can use this to add the user as a vendor. As of right now I can get the user params no problem but the skiswap params I can't seem to get them to comeover I have tried. if I hardcode it it will work so I'm close but can not figure this out

Inside my
skiswap#index I have this for the search Above this I use @skiswap

```
    <%= form_tag search_vendors_path, remote: true, method: :get do %>
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <div class ="input-group col-sm-3">
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Shop name, email, or contact...", autofocus: true, class: "form-control form-control-sm"%>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn btn-info btn-sm", id: "small-serach" do %>
          <i class="fas fa-search" id = "search-icon"></i>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

My search is working and this is what I have in the VendorController

```
  def search
    @users = User.where(["concat_ws(' ' , first_name, last_name, email, company ) ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{ render partial: 'skiswaps/result'}
    end
  end
```

My results are here and this is the badge I use to add new vendor, currently I have it hard coded because I cant figure it out. I am using j render for my results... I have tried skiswap_vendors_path(vendor: user, skiswap_id: @skiswap.id) also skiswap_vendors_path(vendor: user, skiswap: @skiswap) @skiswap is showing up as nil. Wasnt sure if it because my results are part of a partail, they dont seem to have the params that should be in show page.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>

        <td><%= link_to "Add", skiswap_vendors_path(vendor: user, skiswap_id: 4),
                                      class: "badge badge-success", method: :post %></td>
        <td> <strong>Shop: </strong><%= user.company  %> </td>
        <td> <strong>Contact: </strong><%= user.first_name  %> <%= user.last_name %>, <%= user.email%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Then in my VendorController I have this to create, which only works if I hardcode it

```
  def create
   vendor = User.find(params[:vendor])
   skiswap = Skiswap.find(params[:skiswap_id])
    skiswap.vendors.build(user_id: vendor.id)
    if skiswap.save
      flash[:notice] = "You add #{vendor.company} as a vendor"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Sorry something went wrong, try again later"
    end
  end
```

This is what I have for routes

```
  get 'search_vendors', to: 'vendors#search'
  resources :skiswaps do
    resources :vendors
  end
```

Comment: `@skiswap` is not initialized in the `search` action, where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: It's initialized in the index (skiswap controller),  and my search results are displayed in the skiswap index page... I am not sure how to initialize through the search action... I see what you are saying now. I did try and pass the skiswap params through when hitting search but got a two many arguments

Comment: @Eyeslandic Thank you show much I just needed someone to point that out. I have added a <%= hidden_field_tag %> to pass through the extra variable

Comment: Glad to help, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had to add in a hidden field tag to get the @skiswap.id through

```
  <%= form_tag search_vendors_path, remote: true, method: :get do %>
    ....
          <%= hidden_field_tag :skiswap_id, @skiswap.id %>
  
  <% end %>
```